# How to pick multiple images from gallery?

Tags: android, android-image, picker

In my application I allow to user to select multiple images to create pdf.

Issue is user is not able to select more than 1 images. I tried a lot but didn't get any perfect solution which can help me.

There are lot many lib available but i don't want to use it due to some reason.

I am looking for solution with native only.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple by putting extra:

```
int RESULT_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1; 

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select pictures"), RESULT_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Note that there is no requirement for any `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementation to necessarily support `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`. This is a request, not a demand.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Thanks its worked, but not in all device. In Motorola its working fine but in samsung again same issue, allowing only single image selection. Please help.

Comment: @RohanPatel: If you are using the code shown in this answer, not all devices will support it. There is nothing that you can do about that. Either live with the limitation, or create your own UI for this (purely on your own or using one of the libraries that you mentioned in your question).